# Why are getExternalStoragePublicDirectory and getExternalFilesDir are not supported on API level 4?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to follow [Saving Files](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteExternalStorage") reference. Why are `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` and `getExternalFilesDir` *not* supported on API level 4?

Right now i am using some of their example apps that supports API level 4
i use the following code:

```
public File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) {
    // Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory. 
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
    if (!file.mkdirs()) {
        //Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Directory not created");
        System.out.println("Directory not created"); 
    }
    return file;
}
```

And i get the following error: `Call requires API level 8 (current min is 4): android.os.Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`.

Is there anything else i could use for 4 ?

Comment: Why would you support API 4? Just move your minSdkVersion up to API 8.

Comment: well in the future i will work with API 7 as my lowest but now as a practice and for learning purpose i work with api level 4

Comment: That's a bad learning routine, IMO. No one is on API 4, you're just going to be learning a bunch of workarounds that aren't of any use. API 8 is the lowest worth targeting at this time. API 4 is literally 0.1% of the market (http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).

Comment: yea i know, but it was just a practice, however i will still need to use api level 7 support package for 8 and up till api level 11 by what i understand.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it here is the solution:

Both `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` and `getExternalFilesDir` are supported only from api level 8 and above so i had to use something alternative:

```
File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();// gave me the SDcard path.
```

and then i just added the url/path of the application as described in [ref](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternalits)

```
String sdCardDirectory = sdCardRoot + "/Android/data/" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
```

I then Initiated a new File class and created the directories required with `mkdirs()`. and then I initiate another file class with the new address and create the actual file here is how it looks like:

```
        File file = new File(sdCardDirectory, "files");

        if(file.mkdirs() || file.isDirectory()){
            System.out.println("works.");
        }
        file = new File(file, albumName);
        try{
            if(file.createNewFile()){
                System.out.println("File Created");
            }else{
                System.out.println("File Already Exsists");
            }
        }catch (IOException ExceptionS) {
            System.out.println("Encountered the following Exception: " + ExceptionS);
        }

        if (!file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File Does not Exist");

        }else{
            System.out.println("File Exist!");

        }
```

I am pretty sure there are better way of doing this, however i am new to android development.

Hope that helps anyone.